# Teradata query does not wait for the lock to be released

Tags: java, teradata, dropwizard

I have a DropWizard project, which connects to Teradata for CRUD operations. There's an API in the project, which calls a stored procedure in Teradata. The stored procedure executes an UPDATE on a Teradata table(say, table1).

When this API is called by multiple users simultaneously, few fail with Teradata error "ABORTed due to Deadlock".

The question is, how do I make the queries wait in a queue, and retry execution after the lock on table1 is released? Is there any DropWizard configuration related to this?

Comment: There's no need to make the query wait, simply code the Stored Procedure using a proper transaction. Which SQL statemnents are used in the SP?

Comment: @dnoeth SP has a SELECT statement, few IF conditions, and an UPDATE statement

Comment: In the SP start a transaction, do the Select & Update and commit the transaction.

Comment: I tried, and again it's failing. I also noticed one thing, if I execute the SP simultaneously from SQL Assistant, it works. It's only when we call from the API it fails with "Transaction ABORTed due to Deadlock" error. So I suppose it's some DropWizard issue.

Comment: When the transaction is correctly coded there can't be a deadlock. Can you show the SP source?

Comment: @PriyankGupta - I'm going to guess in SQL Assistant your transaction mode is TERA and DropWizard is ANSI. The default transaction mode for ODBC and .Net Provider tend to be Teradata Mode. Did you make sure your transaction modes were the same? As mentioned, source code would be helpful.

Comment: @RobPaller: You can't run a Stored Procedure created in ANSI mode in TERA mode and vice versa.

Comment: @dnoeth thanks. I had forgotten that subtlety.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I cannot post the source code. But we did manage to get around the deadlock situation by using views. We created a view(with row hash lock) on the table being updated, and the issue seems to have disappeared. Thanks again for your help.